# В чем преимущество библиотек для юнит тестов?

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты

По факту юнит тест- это набор входных данных и выходных для тестирования какого-то модуля, если все норм., то мы получаем зеленый цвет, иначе красный. По моему пользуясь таким образом юнит тестами можно спокойно в свой проект добавить какой-то тест класс, который будет тестировать таким образом весь проект. Тут как бы все понятно, так в чем преимущество библиотек для юнит тестов. Например, я создаю проект в блокноте собираю с помощью Мэйкфайла, сколько я потрачу времени на то, чтобы разобраться, как прикрутить готовые библиотеки для юнит тестирования и сколько на то, чтобы написать самому.

Answer (score 1):

Я вчера подключил Nunit и написал первый тест за 10-15 минут, живой пример. Если честно, мне это показалось удобнее, чем создавать отдельный класс. Например Nunit имеет свой GUI, с помощью него все удобно и быстро, а с отдельным классом будет не так, можно, но не стоит.

Comment: Вы умеете `NUnit` + `Native C++`? Расскажите, пожалуйста, подробнее.

Comment: Наверно человек тестирует с# или c++\cli

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать,я не умею это, к сожалению:)

Comment: @alex91

- Ну в таком случае ответ про `NUnit` не имеет никакого отношения к тому, что спрашивает @fortunado.

- Если по теме, то автору вопроса стоит посмотреть в сторону фреймворков типа [`googletest`](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/) и [`boost::test,`](www.boost.org/libs/test/‎) а также понять, что самостоятельная реализация `test`-фреймворка — это отличный способ выстрелить себе в обе ноги сразу и потерять все преимущества от юнит-тестирования. Как можно тестировать что-то, не имея уверенности в том, что используемый механизм для написания тестов *корректен?*

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, я привел частный пример того, что для того, чтобы начать работать с тест-фреймворками нужно не очень много времени. Удобнее, чем писать что-то свое, чем не по теме, простите?

Answer (score 0):

Преимущество исключительно в удобстве и автоматизированности. А вообще можно обойтись без фреймворков или написать свой, под свои нужды. Видимо, поэтому их столько и понаписано. Нужды у всех разные. И представления об удобстве тоже. Я, например, тоже свой написал, для C99. Простой, как валенок, но при этом умеющий сравнивать массивы, чего нигде не видел.

Пример TDD без фреймворков - http://www.slideshare.net/amritayan/test-driven-development-in-c

Answer (score -1):

Юниттесты созданы для тестирования того, как поведёт себя прога в той или иной ситуации. Ошибки в нём, – это как правило, исключения, которые нельзя просто так проигнорировать. Я посмотрю на вас, как будете создавать в блокноте многотысячный проект со многими файлами. Юниттесты бывают разные, но они созданы для маленьких проектов, которые можно набрать в блокноте.

Comment: Airhand, да запросто. По-русски unit test - это "модульное тестирование", то есть наборы тестов для оценки работоспособности модулей, или даже отдельных функций, а не обязательно программы в целом. И как раз при разработке больших проектов могут быть очень полезны, например, как часть регресс-тестов.

Comment: Вот именно отдельные функции и тестируют, всё равно когда в файле много тысяч строк и таких файлов – много, набирать их в нотепаде как-то идеи не возникает.

Comment: Да при чём тут нотепад? Я свои проекты вообще часто в mc или фаре редактирую :) К юнит тестам это вообще никаким боком не относится.

Comment: Да при том, что ТС создаёт проги в ноутпаде.